# I am trying to install rake using the command gem install rake on mac terminal, but I keep getting this error

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems, rake

$ gem install rake
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
Stephens-MBP-2:lib stephengiardina$

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it means you have no access rights on that directory. might be owned by root.

try running the following command:

```
sudo chmod a+rwx  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
```